# Why Solr query not working on whitespaces?

Tags: solr

I am a beginner in **Solr**, I have the following collection in my Soleserver indexed :

```
{
        "id": "book5",
              "title": [
          "Five point someone"
        ],
        "author": "Chetan Bagat",
        "genere": "fantasy",
        "description": [
          "An iit guide"
        ],
        "comments": [
          "good",
          "excellent"
        ],
        "publications": [
          "swapnapublications",
          "pb publications"
        ]
      }
```

and

```
{
        "id": "book1",
        "title": [
          "nightatcallcenter"
        ],
        "author": "ChetanBagat",
        "genere": "fiction",
        "description": [
          "Aniitguide"
        ],
        "comments": [
          "good",
          "excellent"
        ],
        "publications": [
          "bangalorepublications",
          "aswinpublications"
        ]
      }
```

my query q=Five +point+someone is failing

but my query

q=nightatcallcenter holds good why is it so? how can i make the first query work

My schema :

```
 <fields>
        <field name="id" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
        <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/ 
            <field name="genere" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
            <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
            <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
            <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field name="publications" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
            <copyField  source='*' dest='fulltext'/>
            <field name='fulltext' type='text_general' multiValued='true '/>
 </fields>
```

Comment: where you enter this query? JAVA api?

Comment: command line in linux

Comment: could you post then exact curl command you're using?

Comment: curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/newcollection/select?q=Five+point+someone&wt=json&indent=true'

Comment: curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/newcollection/select?q=nightatcallcenter&wt=json&indent=true' this is working but above query is not

Comment: Use `localhost:8983/solr/newcollection/select?q="Five point someone"&wt=json&indent=true`. If it works, I will explain it.

Comment: Tried it already but not showing any response at all

Comment: Make a try by adding the line `<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>` in the beggining of your `text_general` fieldType !

Comment: @Mysterion did u get any lead?

Comment: @alexf still the same after adding the tokenizer

Comment: If you reindex, it should work !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87374/discussion-between-aswin-raghavan-and-alexf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is the fact that with using `text_general`, you will create a single token. When you are searching for `Five +point+someone`, you are looking for three tokens:

1. Five
2. point
3. someone

The clean solution that you can use is to create a custom `text_general` which will be like:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alexf the tockenizer worked perfectly

`<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
    <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
    </fieldType>`

Comment: Please explain me in personal chat

Comment: ok let us continue [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87374/discussion-between-aswin-raghavan-and-alexf)