# Solr MoreLikeThis handler returns 0 elements

Tags: solr, morelikethis

**EDIT:** After changing the search field (mlt.fl) with another with the same features (type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"), it started working as it should.
 'description' field is not empty in every documents so I don't know the reason of this difference, but if I'll discover more I will write here. I won't delete this question in the hope it will useful as a list of common solutions of the same problem.

I have some documents indexed with Solr v. 4.0.0 and I'm trying to obtain similar documents to a given one, but I'm getting no results.
What I have done: 
 
1. in *schema.xml*, I've modified the field I want to search for, adding termVectors="true":

```
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" />
```

2. In *solrconfig.xml* I've added a RequestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="mlt.fl">description</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

3. I've restarted Solr and I execute this query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mlt?q=id:123456&mlt.match.include=false
```

I expect to get some documents with the field 'description' similar to the 'description' field of document with id=123456, but I obtain an empty response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">31</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

Description field is filled in every document.
I've tried to:

- changing the tokenizer of the field type text_general from StandardTokenizerFactory to WhitespaceTokenizerFactory (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092722/why-solr-query-not-working-on-whitespaces))
- using the MoreLikeThisComponent instead of MoreLikeThisHandler, with a query like:

  http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=id:123456&mlt=true&mlt.fl=description
- Changing the mintf (0,1,..), mindf (0,1,..), qf (description) and boost (true, false) params in default values in *schema.xml* as well as in queries (with both /select and /mlt).

Nothing of above works. Solr works perfectly with all other query types. I have no clue about what can be wrong, as I've followed all guides and tutorial I've found (also a lot of answers here). Any ideas about?

Comment: Try with `mlt.match.include` set to `true` - make sure it actually matches a document first :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it does and matches the right document. I've set it to false just to shorten the response

Comment: How many documents have you indexed? The `mintf` and `mindf` values default to 2 and 5, so if less than five documents have the terms, they won't be included. Try giving `mlt.mintf=1` and `mlt.mindf=1` to relax the requirement.

Comment: I have about 800 documents, I've already tried with mintf=1 and mindf=1 (even with 0), but it keeps returning 0 docs